# ¿Como puedo leer variables de un api rest?

Tags: nodejs, angular, webservice, angular9

estoy trabajando con Nodejs(Postgresql) en el backend , y Angular(9) en el Frontend  , consumo el api rest atraves de un servicios de angular.

este es mi api (https://puntoventa3-api.herokuapp.com/puntoventa/api/product/getcat)
[image: https://puntoventa3-api.herokuapp.com/puntoventa/api/product/getcat]

este es mi servicio en angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {


  API_URI = 'https://puntoventa3-api.herokuapp.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getProductForCategory(deploy: string, resource: string, superID: string) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}/puntoventa/api/product/getcat`, {
      deploy,
      resource,
      superID
    });
  }
  
}
```

Puedo imprimir el api de siguiente manera  :

```
 CargarData(inSUPER){
    this.DataService.getProductForCategory(this.deploy,this.resource,inSUPER ).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data['items']);
        this.productos = data['items'];
      }
    );
```

lo cual me devuelve lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera obtener solo `prod_images`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

*Bueno para obtener solo **prod_images** sería de la siguiente manera:*

```js
const items = data['items'];
const lProdImages = [];

for(const item of items) {
  lProdImages.push(item.prod_images);
}
```

*Debes crearte un for, y en este caso usé una variable local para la lista que se llena **"lProdImages"** puedes definirla global como lo hiciste con la variable **productos***

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de la siguiente forma después que el servicio responda:

```
const images = data['items'].map(r => r.prod_images));
```

Tambien lo puedes hacer directamente sobre el flujo de datos

```
return this.http.get(`${environment.url}/resources`).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => resp.prod_images)
    );
```